# "SELECT" selects wrong rows when umlauts are present in table

Tags: mysql, utf-8

The structure of table 'textconstraint' (collation utf8_general_ci) is as follows:

```
+-----+---------+
| id  | pattern |
+-----+---------+
|  11 | Ä       |
|  27 | A       |
+-----+---------+
```

When I query

```
SELECT * FROM textconstraint WHERE pattern = 'A' LIMIT 1;
```

The following rows are selected

```
+----+---------+
| id | pattern |
+----+---------+
| 11 | Ä       |
+----+---------+
```

Why `A-umlaut` is selected instead of `A`?

P.S. I do `SET NAMES UTF8`

Comment: What is selected if you try without LIMIT?

Comment: it is gonna return two records.

Comment: have a look at this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-collation-effect.html

Comment: @fthiella, thanks. This explains everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM textconstraint
WHERE pattern = BINARY 'A'
```

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3dd8d/4).